# How to change shape of Bootstrap button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button

How can I change the round corner button default in bootstrap into normal rectangle button? Now I can only change the size color or the font of the button

```html
.btn-lg {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.btn-sm,
.btn-xs {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The best practice is to create a custom class so you don't change your base CSS in the event you want to use it elsewhere, then apply your changes.

In the example I use .btn.btn-custom-lg, .btn.btn-custom-sm, .btn.btn-custom-xs but if you only want to change something like the `border-radius` for all buttons you can make one global class to apply to the button: `.btn-square { border-radius: 0; }`

See working example.

```css
/*Specific Cases*/

.btn.btn-custom-lg,
.btn.btn-custom-sm,
.btn.btn-custom-xs {
  border-radius: 0;
}
/*Global*/

.btn.btn-square {
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">

  <hr>
  <h3>Specific</h3>
  <div class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-custom-lg">Button Default</div>
  <div class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-custom-sm">Button Default</div>
  <div class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-custom-xs">Button Default</div>
  <hr>
  <h3>Global</h3>
  <div class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-square">Button Default</div>
  <div class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-square">Button Default</div>
  <div class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-square">Button Default</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 22):

Add the class `rounded-0`, as explained on [GetBootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/#border-radius):

```
<a href="tel:+447447218297" class="btn btn-lg btn-success rounded-0"><img src="">Call Now</a>
```

Comment: To confirm for other readers, this applies to bootstrap 4 only however the other solution is better suited for bootstrap 3.

Comment: yes bootstrap 4 for got fix for this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/

Comment: Works in Bootstrap 5 as well. Very nice, short and elegant. Thanks!