# How to change the border-radius of everything in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32976975/4687534), but I need change to square everything in Bootstrap (buttons, text fields, images, ...all)

I think this:

```
<style>
    * {
         border-radius: 0px;
    }
</style>
```

Or I have to specify each class to do this change like in the other answer?
Which is the best way to do it?

Comment: Your best option is to edit and recompile the LESS files.

Comment: Compile your own mix http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ - you can change many attributes e.g. border-radius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think

```
html ~ * {
  border-radius: 0px !important;
  moz-border-radius: 0px !important;
  webkit-border-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

could do the job.